# Ssrs report - On clicking "view report" button nothing happens for one of the user . What could be the cause and resolution?

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

Tried changing order of parameters

Comment: Check the SSRS server logs. Check data source credentials. Check user has access to the data, Check browser version vs other uers etc.